# Is there a way to get the next element in json when i have the previous index or id

Tags: jquery, json

Is there a way to traverse through the json object if i have a key of specific element.

my json is below. If i have a key value of `"1"` , how can i get its next value in the json object i.e Key values corresponding to key `**200**`.

I dont want to use $.each as I have to traverse the json in an onfinish event, so i cant use $.each. Any help would be appriciated

```
**The id will not always be sequential**

{ "root" : [ { "id" : "1",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/89996000?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      },
      { "id" : "200",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/17788981?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      },
      { "id" : "314",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/470742?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      }
    ] }
```

**I want to traverse the json in the below onfinish handler of the vidoe player iam building, basically in $(document).ready function i assign my vidoe player the first trackUrl to be played. Next when the video finisheh playing i want to access the next trackurl which has id = 200**

```
        function onFinish(id) {

            status.text('finished');
            Get next item in the Json object



        }
```

Comment: You want to get the value of the property `trackUrl` right?

Comment: But dont want to iterate the `root` JSON array?

Comment: yes, that's correct. because iam doing processing on an event, so i use first value, on finish of the event processing i need the next value.

Comment: Still i didnt get your requirement...

Comment: 'get its next value in the json object' -- will that always be 'trackUrl'?

Comment: thanks Eyal for responding i have edit my question

Comment: @opensource-ios So why not dealing with json array indexes and you can give the `on finish` handler the `index` against `id`? may be i'm missing something on your logic =)

Answer (score -1):

If you have Ids sequential numbers as array indexes: 0,1,2,3,4..... you can do this:

```
var json= { "root" : [ { "id" : "0",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/89996000?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      },
      { "id" : "1",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/17788981?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      },
      { "id" : "2",
        "trackUrl" : "http://player.vimeo.com/video/470742?api=1&player_id=player1&autoplay=1"
      }
    ] };

var root = json.root, currentId=0;
alert(root[currentId+1].trackUrl);
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can give it a try or adjust it to your application.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BqR33/)

**UPDATE:**
I think you have to deal with array indexes whatever you have as `id` value, by keeping trace of the current index on your `player` application just like a `photoViewer` application, because since you have the current index you can get the next one easily and update your current index holder.

Comment: Hi fares, thanks a lot for your reply.  They wont be sequential all the time, i took that for a example. I have made edits to the question.

Comment: Okay, can you add the `onfinish event handler`, just to have the context of use

Comment: Sure would add that in a moment

Comment: Hi Fares, i have added it